# Laravel connection attribute ignored with hasmanythrough

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

#### Summary

I am trying to use `hasManyThrough` relationship with tables from different connections.

#### Description of the problem:

When defining a `hasManyThrough` relationship, the `protected $connection` attribute is ignored.

#### Steps To Reproduce:

Create the following models (Abbreviated code)

```php
class Resource extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'tcollect'

    public function absences()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('ARM\TargetHoraire\Absence', 'ARM\Tcollect\ICO\ICOExternalReference', 'RecordID', 'ResourceID', 'ID', 'ExternalKey');
    }
}
```

```php
class Absence extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Absences';
    protected $connection = 'punch';
}
```

```php
class ICOExternalReference extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'ICOExternalReferences';
    protected $connection = 'tcollect';
}
```

Then call the relationship on the resource model
`$resource->absences;`

Notice that `ICOExternalReference` $connection attribute is ignored. It tries to use the ICOExternalReference from the `punch` connection.

#### Question

Is there any problem with my code or is there aworkaround to solve this problem?
I have created an issue on the framework repo, but it got closed right away.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
hasMany(class with all parameter)
```